# Why rails 5 link_to is triggering GET request twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using link_to and sending param with it.

```
<%= link_to "Create new environment", new_environment_path(:project => @project.id) %>
```

And trying to use it in the form like below.

```
<%= form.hidden_field :project_id, value: params[:project] %>
```

But the issue is that rails is receiving the GET request twice. First time with project param and the second time without param.

```
07:31:09 rails.1 | 2020-02-06T07:31:09 [I|app|a82ba4dd] Started GET "/environments/new?project=1" for 192.168.121.1 at 2020-02-06 07:31:09 +0000
07:31:10 rails.1 | 2020-02-06T07:31:10 [I|app|cf3eb6ce] Rendered .vendor/ruby/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (906.3ms)
07:31:10 rails.1 | 2020-02-06T07:31:10 [I|app|a82ba4dd] Processing by EnvironmentsController#new as HTML
07:31:10 rails.1 | 2020-02-06T07:31:10 [I|app|a82ba4dd] Parameters: {"project"=>"1"}
07:31:10 rails.1 | 2020-02-06T07:31:10 [D|tax|a82ba4dd] Current location set to Default Location



07:31:10 rails.1 | 2020-02-06T07:31:10 [I|app|306b9b09] Started GET "/environments/new" for 192.168.121.1 at 2020-02-06 07:31:10 +0000
07:31:10 rails.1 | 2020-02-06T07:31:10 [I|app|306b9b09] Processing by EnvironmentsController#new as HTML
07:31:10 rails.1 | 2020-02-06T07:31:10 [D|tax|306b9b09] Current location set to Default Location
07:31:10 rails.1 | 2020-02-06T07:31:10 [D|tax|306b9b09] Current organization set to Default Organization
```

Because of this form is created with the hidden tag where there is no value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="environment[project_id]">
```

I am expecting below

```
<input type="hidden" name="environment[project_id]" value="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

probably the jquery library has been included twice.
check for jquery, jquery_ujs, rails_ujs duplication in assets/javascripts/application.js.